# Which cipher to use for cross-platform

Tags: security, encryption, cross-platform

I have multiple applications which work with one centralized Oracle database.

The applications are targeted on following platforms:

- iPhone
- Android
- Windows (XP, Vista and 7)
- Linux
- Mac Os
- Web applications (ASP.NET, PHP and JSP)

I want to know which kind of cipher I should use to make sure all my encrypted data will be readable (decrypted) for all my application

E.g. 3DES or RIJNDAEL_256 or TWOFISH256?

Comment: All standard ciphers are cross-platform.  You should choose a secure (not 3DES) cipher that meets your needs.

Comment: This is pretty much an opinion question, but I would use Rijndael.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to implement those ciphers on all of the target platforms you mentioned.

As for which to use, I'd suggest Rijndael (AES) since it has received a lot of attention and has a proven security track-record.

Answer (score 3):

http://gpg4browsers.recurity.com/ has JS implementations for all ciphers you mentioned.

All OSes you mentioned support all of these ciphers either directly or via mcrypt.

This reduces the question to opinionizing: So here is my opinion - do NOT standardize (in the sense of hardcode) to any of those ciphers, but invest the on-time penalty to develop your apps and protocols in a way, that allows them to handshake the cipher used. This way you can trade speed for security now and are open for developments in cryptography (or cryptanalysis)

Comment: @Polynomial: On the contrary; that allows an active attacker to force the weakest available cipher.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300806.aspx

Comment: @SLaks - Yes, but only if the configuration of the server isn't updated to prevent this. When a cipher becomes dangerously weak, it can be disabled on the server side and a request for the client to upgrade their software can be shown.

Comment: @SLaks Outright stupid implementations are not the idea's fault. As Polynomial already pointed out, it has to be the server who commands which ciphers are allowed. I also fail to see, how a hardcoded cipher would fare better, if the cipher were found to be insecure.

Comment: @EugenRieck: That doesn't stop MITM; both sides must have a cipher blacklist.

Comment: Again I fail to see, how a hardcoded algorithm would change anything about that, please elaborate!

Comment: Additionally, a MITM needs to know the key, which should never cross the wire. There are tons of literature on how to achieve that.

Comment: @EugenRieck: I meant that making the server reject old algorithms won't stop an MITM attacker from asking the client for an old algorithm, then going to the server with a newer algorithm.  On further thought, once the attacker has done that, you're already in trouble.